# when my message contains English & Chinese & Japanese ,I want to translate to Chinese ,but it doesn't work, hope you help me ,thx

Tags: microsoft-translator

my message for test is:

```
{"message":"你好吗how are you社会の残りの部分",}
```

after translate into Chinese what I get is:

```
{Data":{"messageLanguage":"ja","translateLast":"你好嗎霍 are you 社會的其餘部分"}}
```

Comment: if you have mixed language content, you should consider translating to English first, and then to Chinese, in two steps

Comment: or translate the parts in different languages separately.